# Parse datetime string into year, month, and day variables

Tags: php, string, date-parsing

I have string with following format:

```
$date = "2012-07-22 17:48:24";
```

I want to get the year, month and date in the variables and ignore the time. I am trying following:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = split('[-]', $date);
```

This returns correct values to `$year` and `$month`, but the `$day` gets: `"22 17:48:24"`, while I want to get only 22.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of exploding the value you could use a DateTime object:

```
<?php
$date = "2012-07-22 17:48:24";
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);

var_dump(array(
    'year' => $dateTime->format('Y'),
    'month' => $dateTime->format('m'),
    'day' => $dateTime->format('d'),        
));
```

This would be the most flexible option imho.

As @zerkms noted in his comment you could also use `strtotime()` and `date()`, but I find myself only using the `DateTime` class lately. Not only because it has a nice OO API, but also because it will keep on working after the year 2038 :-). The comment is not wrong though.

Comment: @zerkms don't you mean, `strtotime` + `date` + `date` + `date` ?

Comment: @salathe: yep, `date` + `date` + `date` instead of `format` + `format` + `format`. And it would be shorter ;-P

Comment: My answer would be even shorter.

Comment: @zerkms Scroll down, it has been here for 10 minutes already.

Answer (score 4):

There's also the [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/sscanf) function.

```
sscanf('2012-07-22 17:48:24', '%d-%d-%d', $year, $month, $day);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$date = "2012-07-22 17:48:24";
$date = explode(" ", $date);
list($year, $month, $day) = split('[-]', $date[0]);
```

EDIT:

You should use explode for the date too:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date[0]);
```

The use of split is discouraged as it was deprecated.

Comment: Any reason to use `split` if there is `explode`?

Comment: there is no a reason to even left in the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = "2012-07-22 17:48:24";
preg_match('~^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$~', $date, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtoime("2012-07-22 17:48:24"));
list($year, $month, $day) = split('[-]', $date);
```